# How to Add Tooltip To BoxPlot Chart Using C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, charts, tooltip

I have created box plot chart dynamically but would like to add a **tooltip to the box plot chart** so that when user mouse over the box plot series, the box plot series values will be displayed out in tooltip.

This is my code to create box plot chart:

```
                        Chart Chart1= new Chart();
                        Chart1.DataSource = dt;
                        Chart1.Width = 800;
                        Chart1.Height = 490;

                        Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
                        Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.BoxPlot;
                        Chart1.Series.Add(new Series());
                        Chart1.Series[1].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
                        List<object> List1 = dt.AsEnumerable().ToList<object>();

                        int Chart1_AVG = 0;
                        int Chart1_POINTINDEX = 0;

                        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                        {
                            Chart1_AVG = (int)row["AVG"];

                            Chart1.Series[0].Points.AddXY(row["CUSTOMER"], new object[] { row["MIN"], row["MAX"], row["25TH_PCT_NUMBER"], row["75TH_PCT_NUMBER"], row["50TH_PCT_NUMBER"], row["AVG"] });
                            Chart1_POINTINDEX = Chart1.Series[1].Points.AddXY(row["CUSTOMER"], new object[] { row["AVG"] });

                            if ((Chart1_AVG >= AvgMinColorGreen) && (Chart1_AVG <= AvgMaxColorGreen))
                            {
                                Chart1.Series[1].Points[Chart1_POINTINDEX].MarkerColor = Color.Green;
                            }
                            else if ((Chart1_AVG >= AvgMinColorYellow) && (Chart1_AVG <= AvgMaxColorYellow))
                            {
                                Chart1.Series[1].Points[Chart1_POINTINDEX].MarkerColor = Color.Orange;
                            }
                            else if ((Chart1_AVG >= AvgMinColorRed) && (Chart1_AVG <= AvgMaxColorRed))
                            {
                                Chart1.Series[1].Points[Chart1_POINTINDEX].MarkerColor = Color.Red;
                            }
                        }
                        Chart1.Series[0]["BoxPlotShowMedian"] = "false"; //hide the average point

                        //create chartareas
                        ChartArea ca= new ChartArea();

                        //databind
                        Chart1.DataBind();
                        Chart1.Visible = true;

                        panel.Controls.Add(Chart1);
```

Please help me on this, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
Chart1.Series[0].ToolTip = "#VAL"
```

Other possible tooltips are LegendToolTip, LabelToolTip ...

For keywords see https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/dd456687%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: hi @Fratyx, thanks for your reply! May I know what I have to put under "#VAL"?

Comment: #VAL is a keyword (see the link). It is a placeholder for the y value. Just use it as this string "#VAL". You could also use "My value is #VAL" and it would be replaced by e.g. "My value is 123".

Comment: hi @Fratyx, ok I got it thanks! Do u know how I can bold the text in tooltip?

Comment: Sorry, don't know. There is a GetToolTip event but you can only influence the text and the position but not the font of the tooltip in it.